# Window hooks - How do they work?

Tags: windows

I've got no idea how window hooks work at the "system level". MSDN only touches what's going on very briefly:

> A hook is a point in the system message-handling mechanism where an
>   application can install a subroutine to monitor the message traffic in
>   the system and process certain types of messages before they reach the
>   target window procedure.

My best guess is something like below:

[image]

Before each message is added to the message queue for a window, it'll first send the message to the global/local hooks, which may do something, depending on their hook procedures. After all global hooks and local hooks, the message is finally added to the window message queue.

However, MSDN says that for some of the types of hooks, it will monitor `events`, `notifications` etc.

An example is the `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook:

> Installs a hook procedure that monitors low-level **mouse
>   input events**. For more information, see the LowLevelMouseProc hook
>   procedure.

When they say `events`, are we talking window messages, or do they mean something else?

Am I all wrong?

Comment: Bonus style points for an image of a freehand diagram.

Comment: Here is a little explanation http://b.1asphost.com/mmbaig/Tutorials/Windows_Hooks.html

Comment: Many hooks are message based.  But not the hook you are talking about, it is actually triggered by an "event".  It runs just *before* Windows creates the message and puts it in the message queue of the window that has the focus.  Compare to WH_MOUSE, a global hook that runs when an app call Get/PeekMessage and is about to retrieve a mouse message from the message queue.  Thus actually triggered by a message.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm a bit confused... you're saying that a global hook is created at application level - however the article linked to by Orhan Cinar, says that A global hook will execute at system level. A local hook on the other side, will execute at application level.

Comment: I don't know what "system level" means.  The two local hooks are indeed special, Windows doesn't need a DLL injected into a process to execute them.  Because they are not message based and thus don't have affinity to a particular thread's message queue.

Comment: @HansPassant, By system level I simply meant the "system message loop" (see the article Orhan Cinar linked). - "The two local hooks are indeed special" - I'm not sure which 2 hooks you're talking about, but I suspect it's WH_MOUSE and WH_MOUSE_LL. They're not necessarily local. According to MSDN they can be either global or local. - Just to make sure: `event` doesn't refer to the kernel object right?

Comment: No, WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL, the two low-level hooks.  They don't require a DLL to be injected.

Comment: @HansPassant, Ah - I see. If you take a look at the first diagram in the linked article, then there's an arrow with the text "input (hardware interrupts)" - Is that the place where "input events" are handled?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a mechanism for windows messages, you can process this data (messages) before they reach target window procedure (message loop).

If you want hook other process windows you can simply do this in DLL, and use DLL injection for inject your library to other process.